# Static initialization when it is not required

Tags: c++, initialization

Quote from 3.6.2/3 of N3797 C++14 final working draft:

> An implementation is permitted to perform the initialization of a
>   non-local variable with static storage duration as a static
>   initialization even if such initialization is not required to be done
>   statically, provided that
>
> — the dynamic version of the initialization does not change the value
>   of any other object of namespace scope prior to its initialization,
>   and
>
> — the static version of the initialization produces the same value in
>   the initialized variable as would be produced by the dynamic
>   initialization if **all variables** not required to be initialized
>   statically were initialized dynamically.

What does all variable have to initialization of one specific variable?

If it possible, describe the latter point by example.

Comment: Please clarify your question it took me 5 reads to understand it (e.g., To which variables the quote "all variables" refers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This matters when the initialiser of one variable refers to another variable.

```
constexpr int f(int);

extern const int a = f(1); // not required to be statically initialized
extern const int b = a; // also not required to be statically initialized

constexpr int f(int x) { return x; }
```

Now suppose that the implementation chooses to statically initialize `b`, but dynamically initialize `a`. In that case, the initialization of `b` would take place before that of `a`. The text you ask about explains that this doesn't permit an implementation to initialize `b` to zero: even if `b` is initialized first, its value must be `f(1)`, which is `1`.

Comment: Clear example! Thanks.

Comment: One moment: I don't understand why does extern const int a = -1U; not required to be stacially? -1U is constant exression, isnt'it?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv `-1U` is a constant expression of type `unsigned int`, but as far as I'm aware, since the conversion of an out-of-range value to a signed integer type is implementation-defined, `(int) -1U` isn't (and the conversion is implicit in my example). I'll double-check, and if it turns out I picked a bad example, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv I'm not entirely sure, but I think you're right that I picked a bad example, and that even the implementation-defined result leaves the expression as constant. I've edited to pick a better example.

Comment: Is constexpr function call really not constant expression?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv It's a constant expression when the function is defined, but I'm using it before its definition, and in that case, it isn't (and cannot be) a constant expression.